# Is there a good utility / 3rd party library to manage the AppEngine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore, bulk

I have been developing an app using appengine.  We are likely to be storing a lot of records in the datastore but I find the admin functionality you are given to manage this data lacking.

As an example, there are no good ways to bulk delete a bunch of data - you have to write a class of your own to do this.

Before I start down the path of building the admin ui and features I need to manage the datastore entities, I was wondering if anyone knows of a good 3rd party tool that's already been written to do this for me?  Something that has basic CRUD functionality plus bulk import and bulk export features.

I am using the Python SDK.

Comment: you can bulk delete entities since SDK 1.3.8

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified whether you're using the Java or Python SDK, but if you're using Java App Engine, I suggest using the [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) framework to interact with the datastore rather than the standard JDO/JPA method. It's much nicer.

Comment: Sorry - I'm using the python SDK.